# Remove the time from datetime.datetime in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas column called `'date'`
which has values and type like `2014-07-30 00:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>`.
I want to remove the time from the date.The end result being `2014-07-30' in datetime.datetime format.

I tried a bunch of solutions like-

```
df['PSG Date '] = df['PSG Date '].dt.date
```

but its giving me error-

```
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you should begin with a `datetime` series; if you don't have one, use `pd.to_datetime` to force this conversion. This will permit vectorised computations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['2014-07-30 12:19:22', '2014-07-30 05:52:05',
                           '2014-07-30 20:15:00']})

df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
```

Next, note you cannot remove time from a `datetime` series in Pandas. By definition, a `datetime` series will include both "date" and "time" components.

#### Normalize time

You can use [`pd.Series.dt.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`pd.Series.dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) to reset the time component to `00:00:00`:

```
df['col_floored'] = df['col'].dt.floor('d')
df['col_normalized'] = df['col'].dt.normalize()

print(df['col_floored'].iloc[0])     # 2014-07-30 00:00:00
print(df['col_normalized'].iloc[0])  # 2014-07-30 00:00:00
```

#### Convert to datetime.date pointers

You can convert your `datetime` series to an `object` series, consisting of `datetime.date` objects representing dates:

```
df['col_date'] = df['col'].dt.date
print(df['col_date'].iloc[0])        # 2014-07-30
```

Since these are not held in a contiguous memory block, operations on `df['col_date']` will not be vectorised.

#### How to check the difference

It's useful to check the `dtype` for the series we have derived. Notice the one option which "removes" time involves converting your series to `object`.

Computations will be non-vectorised with such a series, since it consists of pointers to `datetime.date` objects instead of data in a contiguous memory block.

```
print(df.dtypes)

col               datetime64[ns]
col_date                  object
col_floored       datetime64[ns]
col_normalized    datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe need first [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and for `date`s use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['PSG Date '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date '], errors='coerce').dt.date
```

If want datetimes with no times use [`dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html):

```
df['PSG Date '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date '], errors='coerce').dt.floor('d')
```

Comment: What is error? `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` ?

Comment: Now there is no error but the answer is coming 2014-07-30 00:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

Comment: The time has not removed only the type has changed from datetime.datetime to pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - It is excepcted output of to_datetime, if use `df['PSG Date '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date ']).dt.date` it still dont work?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date ']).dt.date gives the error TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime

Comment: and if use `df['PSG Date '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PSG Date '], errors='coerce').dt.date` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174816/discussion-between-ubuntu-noob-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `datetime.datetime` to `date time.date` by calling the `.date()` method of the object. eg

```
 current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
 date_only = current_datetime.date()
```

Comment: I have a pandas column...how to make changes in that?

Comment: In reply to ubuntu_noob: df[datetimeColumn].transform(lambda x: x.date())