# Converting a date format from a csv. file in python from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+00:00 to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with one of the columns being 'dates' (being a dtype: object) where I have a format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS+00:00` (there is a space between the days and the hours) but I want to simplify this by just having the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Is there a way to cut off the HH:MM:SS+00:00 with a few lines of code? I've tried using but it didn't work:

```
pd.to_datetime(combined_csv['dates'], format='%Y-%m-%dT')
```

Any suggestions?

[image: Image of the dataframe that i am using]

Comment: If working with ***string dtype***, just `combined_csv['dates'].str.split(' ').str[0]`.  If working with ***datetime dtype***, floor to the day, `combined_csv['dates'].dt.floor('d')` (does the same as `.dt.normalize()` but is more efficient afaik).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51287504/10197418, also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29310178/10197418 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/50845338/10197418 - however, I would suggest to ***not use `.date`*** as this gives you a Python datetime.date object column. Better keep string or floor pandas datetime to the day (see above comment).

Comment: Thank you so much MrFuppes!! combined_csv['dates'].str.split(' ').str[0] ended up doing the trick. Best wishes, Tiago

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's useful for you

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("combined.csv")
df[["Date", "Time"]] = df["dates"].str.split(" ", expand=True)
```